# Datasets like MNIST for image classification

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

For my thesis, I developed some tensor-based algorithms for image classification. I have been using the MNIST dataset as benchmark for quite some time now but I want to test my algorithms on other datasets. Because I need images that are already preprocessed (centered, rotated, ...) there aren't much datasets I can use. For example, the COIL datasets contains images of objects that are rotated which isn't good. I have found one other dataset with faces that I can use but are there any other already preprocessed dataset I can use?

Comment: *Because I need images that are already preprocessed (centered, rotated,* **and** *the COIL datasets contains images of objects that are rotated which isn't good.* You need them rotated but rotated isn't good?? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3):

The [CIFAR-10 dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) consists of 60000 32x32 color images in 10 classes, with 6000 images per class. So, that is a decent pre-processing I feel.

You can train on [ImageNet](http://www.image-net.org/) which consists of hundreds and thousands of images belonging to thousands of classes, though not exactly pre-processed in terms of uniform image size. Microsoft Common Objects in Context (COCO) and CIFAR-100 Dataset are some other datasets you can try.